# Let $A\subset X$. Show that if $C$ is a connected subspace of $X$ that intersects both $A$ and $X-A$ , then $C$ intersects $\operatorname{Bd}A$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Problem**   Let $A\subset X$. Show that if $C$ is a connected subspace of $X$ that intersects both $A$ and $X-A$ , then $C$ intersects $\operatorname{Bd}A$.

**Attempt**- Suppose $C\cap \operatorname{Bd}A=\varnothing$ then $$C\cap (\overline{A}\cap \overline{X-A})=\varnothing$$

therefore,
$$(C\cap \overline{A})\cap (C\cap \overline{X-A})=\varnothing$$

> **Edit**: If $C\cap A\neq \varnothing$ and $C\cap (X-A)\neq\varnothing$ but $C\cap \operatorname{Bd}A=\varnothing$.
> Then $C\cap (A-\operatorname{Bd}{A})=C\cap A^0\neq \varnothing$ and $C\cap ((X-A)-\operatorname{Bd}(X-A))=C\cap (X-A) ^0\neq \varnothing$

This will form a separation for $C$ if we show that $C\cap \overline{A}$ and $C\cap \overline{X-A}$ are open.Clearly, both sets are non-empty but How will it be open? Am I on right track? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

They are not closed subsets of $C$ (in the subspace topology). It follows that they are also open in this topology because they are each other's complements.

Alternatively,  you can argue as follows: The complement of the boundary of $A$ is the union of  $A^{0}$ (the interior of $A$) and $(A^{c})^{0}$. Since $C \subseteq  A^{0} \cup (A^{c})^{0}$ we get a contradiction to connectedness of $C$.  ( $A^{0}$ and $(A^{c})^{0}$ are disjoint open sets).

Comment: How are they open in subspace topology? I am confused here.

Comment: @AmanPandey True. You only have to realize that a  connected set $C$ cannot be the union of two disjoint **closed** subsets of $C$. 'Open' and 'closed' work equally well.

Comment: As $C\cap \overline{A}$ and $C\cap \overline{X-A}$ are complements of each other's. How? it implies that both are open in subspace topology.

Comment: Every point of $C$ belongs to one of these sets. In fact every point of $X$ belongs to  the closure of $A$ or to the closure of $A^{c}$ (can you verify that?). Since these two sets are also disjoint they are complements of each other in $C$. (Complements taken w.r.t $C$, not $X$). @AmanPandey

Comment: Thank you@ Kavi

Comment: see my recent edits. Is it ok ?